# When asserting an object property, can the method's this type in the asserted field be the object's this?

Tags: typescript

I simplified my code to make it clear

```
type anyFunc = (...arg: any) => any

type anyObject = Record<string, any>

type Instance<A, D, M> = & { data: D } & M

type Opt<A, D, M> = {
    methods: M,
    data: D,
    assertion: A
} & ThisType<Instance<A, D, M>>

function foo<A extends anyObject, D extends anyObject, M extends Record<string, anyFunc>>(opt: Opt<A, D, M>) {

}

foo({

    data: {
        str: 'string',
    },
    methods: {
        M1() {
            this.data.str // string
        }
    },
    assertion: {
        A: {
            M2(data) {
                data // number  ok
                this //   I want ThisType to be the same as M1 .(this.data.str  => string)
            }
        }
    } as { A: { M2: (data: number) => void } },// I have to use assertions for some reason
    // ... B :{ M3（data){ this} as ...}
})
```

I want M2 to have the same thistype as M1, is it possible?
In the real project, I use a generic function to make assertions.

```
    A:<xxx<T>> {
        M2(data){ this } //
    }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgdiAYgVzgYygXigCgHQEwBOA5gFywICUWAfJSAFCOiQMDyARgFYRrBYoAJT4B7IgBMAPAGdgRAJZwSAGga1mraAEk4c+GghSAgmoAiagLL1sAMigBvKBJjAYFM1AC+Ue5c3g0OxgwCbmVjaOjFAxUAC2EMAAFqISMhSWKtGxLm4eWbGwMjIQRMAKonAUxow+9gAqSQoy9YFSuvroRqZQFlDWGowAZqj8FXBQQ6KiJlAQAB7AEHBpHDx8wOZzi8ur8CBcvPxW20srMsJikrLySqoMKOi0tDiiIRTBoT191jQOzF5mFNRDh-tkYrl3FFCoU5EQKAByOF3BEFWJeNExBLJVLpaEwmKWACMOD+4IJsWSzTwkLwcKgAHoGVBkcpyYVARzMUUSmVxhR-hSoMYBeyKZYAEw4SFkoVCyGM5lwZBxTilGKiADWYrlUCpFyZUEqABsQLAYDAoGooNooAB3eACRrNVpsYCiKBqvVJaAyGAJIr9IlQPA4fU01wwOnyGKYeiskhUHUwzkU1MxHwwC5OEWOfoSijSyMUZWq0o0ONQABuogUEm83hUhttSRgVeg7qgyBKPNK5UqFymRBZogDRAgWcq5MNBDwUAAQlAyE5LABmQAQ-zKnPrMxdZ4CvFQgA)

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a type assertion instead of [annotating the `data` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZb5Km).  Does that solve your problem or is something else going on?  (Also note how a [mre] doesn't need those `anyFunc` or `anyObject` types since you're really not asking about constraints on `A`, `D`, and `M` type parameters, are you?)

Comment: According to your answer, I have a new idea. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm happy to write up an actual answer if that meets your needs... does it?